# Python operator overloading __div__

Tags: python

I have a class that has the functions **mul** and **div** implemented as follows:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    return Foo(self.a * other)

def __div__(self, other):
    return Foo(self.a / other)
```

The multiplication (e.g. a * b, where a is an instance of the class Foo and b is an integer) works fine, but the division (a / b) gives an error saying the operator is not supported. How do I get around this?

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Foo' and 'int'
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Have you tried overloading `__truediv__` (`/`) and `__floordiv__` (`//`) instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `from __future__ import division`. So you have to implement `__truediv__` for `/`, and `__floordiv__` for `//`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `__rdiv__`: division with reversed operands.
[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**rdiv**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rdiv__)